# rich text editor for textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

can some of you guys suggest me some free rich text editor for textarea? I like the one that stackoverflow uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I like the one that stackoverflow
> uses.

The one used by StackOverflow is:

[WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/)

Also have a look at this blog post at StackOverflow:

- [Reverse Engineering the WMD Editor](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/reverse-engineering-the-wmd-editor/)

Comment: WMD link no longer valid.

Comment: Mmm... Could It save to .RTF?

Comment: Can't get your link

Answer (score 5):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is what I've used successfully before.  It's configurable to show as much or as little of the editor as you want.

Comment: Mmm... Could It save to .RTF?

Comment: @kokbira: It has been years since I did anything with TinyMCE. I did a web search, but the links I saw were about the rich text editing environment that TinyMCE provides, rather than actually saving in RTF. Sorry I can't provide a better answer.

Comment: @kokbira: After responding, I noticed you asked the same question under the other answers. Is there a reason you didn't search for a more pertinent question, or ask one yourself? There are at least 3 other questions on this site closer to your topic. One of those has an answer suggesting something named quill, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002509/rtf-format-in-web-text-editor .

Answer (score 4):

I think you can choose from these two, the bests I have ever seen:

1. [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
2. [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

Comment: Mmm... Could they save to .RTF?

Comment: @kokbira "I would think that finding an HTML to RTF converter would sound like a better idea than trying to force the editor to change its output format. CKEditor outputs clean, standards-compliant HTML code, so any good converter should be able to handle it nicely."

Comment: @KeyneViana - i am now looking for the best angular free editor,
which one of the two you recommend more? and if you know what is the difference between ckeditor 4 and ckeditor 5 with the angular support (not features)

Comment: @chayaD It looks like CKeditor has better support.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Sir Trevor](http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/) too. It's light, extensible and supports markdown.

Comment: Mmm... Could It save to .RTF?